# Unable to install Skype on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: installation, 10.04, software-center, skype

I'm a 14 year old and absolutely useless at technology. I think its Ubuntu 10.04, and my brother showed me how to do it but he isn't very knowledgeable about my Netbook. So it got all the way up to downloading the package then it said could not download all required files and I don't know what to do?

Comment: While 10.04 is still technically still supported its only supported till May 9.  I suggest you upgrade first then let us know if you are still having a problem with 12.04 or 12.10.  Or wait a few days and 13.04

Answer (score 3):

Since Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx), Skype is part of the Canonical partner repository. To install Skype add the Canonical Partner Repository. You can do this by running the command

Open a Terminal by e.g pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

It will ask for your user password.

Then install Skype via the Software-Center or via the Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```